# Scrollbars when root user

Tags: root, scrollbar

When I open an application as root I get gnome2-like scrollbars which is fine.

But:

1. the small arrows at top and bottom of the scrollbars are missing.
2. the function of clicking between arrow and slider of the scrollbar to "scroll" down one page is also missing, it just jumps to the position of the cursor (making it really hard to scroll through huge list like in Synaptic).

[image: scrollbars as root user]

Is there any way to resolve these issues? Can't they look like in Firefox for example?

Comment: You do know that running graphical apps as root user is mostly unnecessary and can be rather dangerous to your system?

Comment: Sure I know. But for example Synaptic is started as root by default.

Comment: Inherently, Synaptic must be run as root, lest it be rendered useless.

Comment: For Synaptic I figured out that it was the latest BZR build I had installed, just reverted back to Quantal latest version.
Question remains for other applications I run as root user.

Comment: Are you using `sudo` or `gksu` to run your applications?

Comment: Rhetorical question? I always use `gksu` for graphical applications that need root privileges. But how should that help with this question?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a complete answer as I cannot find it in my backups. But I spent about 4 hours trying to remember how I did it last time. So in 2 areas changes are needed. Basically it breaks down to the theme you are using (i.e. mine is Ambiance) and making edits to File `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css` and `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` for the `root` access and `/home/USER/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` for the USER access.

In `gtk-widgets.css` I changed the scrollbar section to have the following and the same is in `~.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css`

```
/*************
* scrollbar *
*************/
.scrollbar,
.scrollbar.vertical {
    -GtkScrollbar-has-backward-stepper: 1;
    -GtkScrollbar-has-forward-stepper: 1;
    -GtkRange-slider-width: 16;
    -GtkRange-stepper-size: 16;
    -GtkRange-stepper-spacing: 0;
    -GtkRange-trough-border: 0;
    -GtkScrollbar-min-slider-length: 30;
```

The next edit maybe different if you are not using the same engine I have for the Gnome-flashback login that gives me Metacity? Find the section in `/usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` that has sub section `engine "murrine" {`
bellow the `style "default" {` section and change:

> engine "murrine" {
>   ... other declarations
>   stepperstyle = 3
>   to
>   stepperstyle = 0

I believe The last line gives the even step scrolling down the page as opposed to jumping to the pointer or it just turns off the overlay-scrollbars? I have not figured out how to do this for something like synaptic.

Comment: So I remembered one other adjustment: in /usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/settings.ini  paste this; 'gtk-primary-button-warps-slider = false'. This will set one page at a time scroll as opposed to jumping to the pointer